# Excel VBA remove overlapping of data into adjacent fields

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a VBA script that incorporates the function to remove the overlapping of data into the adjacent cells and resize the cell to fit the length of the data as shown in the followings snaps.

1) Original layout of data in Excel

[image: Before]

2) Click the top let hand corner to select all fields

[image: Select all fields]

3) Double click on the sides of the cell at the columns to resize cells to fit data lengths.

[image: Double click when this cursor appears]

Currently, I am using `.HorizontalAlignment` below, but it does not work:

```
With wks
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        lastCol = .Columns.Count
        lastRow = .Rows.Count
    End With

    'Select the interested cells and insert borders around the interested fields
    .UsedRange.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .UsedRange.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [Range.AutoFit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820840.aspx) method.

```
Sub allFit()
    Dim c As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
                With .Columns(c)
                    .WrapText = False
                    .AutoFit
                End With
            Next c
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: you could also go
    `With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .Columns.AutoFit
        .WrapText = False
    End With`

Comment: Good point; that would tighten it up a bit. I used the loop to exercise the .columns.count property of currentregion more than anything else.

Comment: Of course I very well knew you knew it... it was just to add something possibly useful to the OP. and I'm a big fan of "tighten it up"!

Comment: Thanks for both your help! I really appreciate it. I managed to solve the issue with the code below:

`.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit`

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this. Simple function, where you first select sheet where to apply, and then use function AutoFit on Columns (which means all columns) and it will size of columns by text length. Also you can select only some columns and etc... but its for different question

```
Sub adjustColumns()
    Sheets("Sheet3").Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```